# Cannot add or update child row, foreign key constraint?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have made the following tables and I am trying to add a player to the player table via an insert.php page and when I try I get the following error message:

> ErrorCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`football_db`.`player`, CONSTRAINT `player_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`teamID`) REFERENCES `team` (`teamID`))

Here is the sql code for my tables, its pretty basic:

```
CREATE TABLE player (
    playerID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    playerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    playerAge int(3) NOT NULL,
    playerNation VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    playerPosition VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    playerTeam VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    teamID int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(playerID),
    FOREIGN KEY(teamID) REFERENCES team(teamID))       ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE team (
    teamID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    teamName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    teamLeague VARCHAR(70),
    yearFounded int(5) NOT NULL,
    teamCrest VARCHAR(30),
    leagueID int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(teamID),
    FOREIGN KEY(leagueID) REFERENCES league(leagueID)) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE league (
    leagueID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    leagueName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    leagueRegion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    leagueSize int(3) NOT NULL,
    leagueLogo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    yearStarted int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(leagueID)) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    user_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    user_email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    user_pass VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)) ENGINE=innodb;
```

And here is my php code on the insert page.

```
<?php 
    include 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['button-submit'])){
        $sql = "insert into player (playerName, playerAge, playerNation, playerPosition, playerTeam) values ('".$_POST['player_name']."', '".$_POST['player_age']."', '".$_POST['player_nation']."', '".$_POST['player_nation']."', '".$_POST['player_team']."')";

        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error'.mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }
?>

<h2>Add player</h2>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Player Name: </label>
    <input name="player_name">
    <br>
    <label>Player Age: </label>
    <input name="player_age">
    <br>
    <label>Player Nation: </label>
    <input name="player_nation">
    <br>
    <label>Player Position: </label>
    <input name="player_position">
    <br>
    <label>Player Team: </label>
    <input name="player_team">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="button-submit">
</form>
```

and my index page to show the data

```
<?php
    require "connect.php"
?>

<h2> Player Lists </h2>

<h3><a href="insertPlayer.php">Add player!</a></h3><br>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Nation</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Team ID</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $sql = 'select playerID, playerName, playerAge, playerNation, playerPosition, playerTeam, teamID from player';
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$row['playerID']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['playerName']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['playerAge']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['playerNation']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['playerPosition']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['playerTeam']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['teamID']?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>

</table>
```

I'm very sorry if this is very basic to most of you but I have just started with php and mysql in college like 2 months ago, my goal is to have the teamID 1 if it is chelsea, 2 if it is another team, 3 if another and 1 again if it is chelsea so on and so forth.

UPDATE

```
<?php 
    include 'connect.php';

    $teamName = $_POST['player_team'];
    $teamID = "select teamID from team WHERE teamName = $teamName";

    if(isset($_POST['button-submit'])){
        $sql = "insert into player (playerName, playerAge, playerNation, playerPosition, playerTeam, teamID) values ('".$_POST['player_name']."', '".$_POST['player_age']."', '".$_POST['player_nation']."', '".$_POST['player_nation']."', '".$_POST['player_team']."', '".$teamName."')";

        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error'.mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }
?>

<h2>Add player</h2>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Player Name: </label>
    <input name="player_name">
    <br>
    <label>Player Age: </label>
    <input name="player_age">
    <br>
    <label>Player Nation: </label>
    <input name="player_nation">
    <br>
    <label>Player Position: </label>
    <input name="player_position">
    <br>
    <label>Player Team: </label>
    <input name="player_team">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="button-submit">
</form>
```

Ok so I have updated the code and now I am getting the error undefined index on line 4 which I cant understand

UPDATE 2

```
  <?php 
    include 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['button-submit'])){
        $teamName = $_POST['player_team'];
        $teamID = "select teamID from team WHERE teamName = ".$_POST['player_team'];

        $sql = "insert into player (playerName, playerAge, playerNation, playerPosition, playerTeam, teamID) values ('".$_POST['player_name']."', '".$_POST['player_age']."', '".$_POST['player_nation']."', '".$_POST['player_position']."', '".$_POST['player_team']."', '".$teamID."')";

        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error'.mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }
?>

<h2>Add player</h2>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Player Name: </label>
    <input name="player_name">
    <br>
    <label>Player Age: </label>
    <input name="player_age">
    <br>
    <label>Player Nation: </label>
    <input name="player_nation">
    <br>
    <label>Player Position: </label>
    <input name="player_position">
    <br>
    <label>Player Team: </label>
    <input name="player_team">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="button-submit">
</form>
```

UPDATE 3

```
<?php 
    include 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['button-submit'])){
        $teamName = $_POST['player_team'];
        $stmt = "SELECT teamID FROM team WHERE teamName = '".$teamName."'";
        $teamID = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO player (playerName, playerAge, playerNation, playerPosition, teamID) values ('".$_POST['player_name']."', '".$_POST['player_age']."', '".$_POST['player_nation']."', '".$_POST['player_position']."', $teamID)";

        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error'.mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160950/discussion-on-question-by-shlongmor-cannot-add-or-update-child-row-foreign-key).

Answer (score 0):

this message happen when you try to update or delete a foreign key and it is a good security practice.
so to prevent it try this

```
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

after the definition of your foreign key like this

```
FOREIGN KEY(teamID) REFERENCES team(teamID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

also for the other table related .